# Spring form, create elements client side usig javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, spring-mvc

I have a spring form, with backing object that includes a LazyList - works hunky dory.

The form initally shows:

```
<tr><td>
<form:textarea path="myList[0]" cssClass="myClass" rows="2" cols="35"/>
</td><tr>
<tr><td>
<form:textarea path="myList[1]" cssClass="myClass" rows="2" cols="35"/>
</td><tr>
```

When a user focusses on the final textarea I want another one to be appended. The html and javascript I have OK, its the binding to the spring backing object that is a problem, my javascript so far:

```
var myStr =  '<tr><td>'+
    '<form:textarea path="myList[2]" cssClass="myClass" rows="2" cols="35"/>'+
    '</td><tr>'     

function myAppend(){
jq('#myTable tr:last').find("textarea").unbind('focus');
jq('#myTable tr:last').after(myStr);
jq('#instructionTable tr:last').find("textarea").bind('focus', function() {
    myAppend();
    });
}
```

However the rendering is screwed up ... any tips ?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890250/better-way-for-dynamic-forms-with-spring/1827558#1827558), which performs and ajax call for each new line. Is their any other option ?

Comment: Are you closing your `<tr>` tags properly? In the example there are no `</tr>`.

Comment: http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439044/dynamic-forms-in-spring/1441302#1441302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spring `<form:textarea ... />` tag is evaluated on server side. 
It renders the according HTML Element based on the given tag parameters.
So a:

```
<form:textarea path="name"/>
```

is rendered to

```
<textarea id="name" name="name"></textarea>
```

So you have to append a `<textarea />` Element with your javascript.

The reason for using the tag is to bind the submited value to the '**commandBean**' provided by your spring controller.

Comment: A solution to that problem is here : http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439044/dynamic-forms-in-spring/1441302#1441302