# Thymeleaf - Input Dynamic List Of String

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to add a dynamic list of input fields from the user. Combine those different inputs and pass them as list from the view to the controller.
This is my domain class

```
public class HTMLPage {

    @Size(min = 3)
    @NotNull
    private List<String> ingredients;
    @Size(min = 5)
    @NotNull
    private List<String> method;
    @Size(min = 3)
    @NotNull
    private String recipeName;
    //getter setters

 }
```

I am completely new to thymeleaf. I have gone through all possible tutorials. There are different ways how to iterate the list but I cannot find a way to **dynamically input list of strings** and send the complete HTMLPage object to my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's more about Spring binder rather than `thymeleaf`. Whenever the user adds a new input, then by using JavaScript you append `<input name="ingredients[0]" />` to the form. After that every time you increment the index by 1, So, the next append will be `<input name="ingredients[1]" />`. and so forth. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441302/3853283) for more info.

Comment: I actually found it on my own with the same solution. But anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you need to do is create a controller for your page. From there you load into spring the information, in your case the list, in my case I used a ModelMap with a lot of different things.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/assessment/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showPage(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
    [...]

    List<Assessment> list = new ArrayList<Assessment>();
    [...]
    model.addAttribute("assessments", list);
    [...]
    model.addAttribute(REQUEST_VIEW, new Gson().toJson(requestView));
    return "assessment"; //name of your page in spring config
}
```

Then put your configuration in Spring and your Pom. From there will be easy access to the information just using the names that you configure.

```
<table class="table-row-selected">
    <tbody>
    <div th:each="assessment : ${assessments}" th:remove="tag">
        <tr th:attr="ng-click='selectedAssessment(\''+ ${assessment.getTypeCode()}+'\' , \'' +${assessment.getName()} +'\', \'' +${assessment.isLookUpSaid()} +'\', \'' +${assessment.getLanguages()} +'\');', ng-mouseover='refreshDescription(\''+ ${assessment.getDescription()}+'\')'">
            <td><strong th:text="${assessment.getName()}"></strong></td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```